# fade out first row in tableView when insert a new row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fadeout

I tried this code to fade out the first cell in tableView but that code work when scrolling the table only I need it work like Instagram live streaming chat

streamController.swift

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -
  > UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatcell", for: 
     indexPath) as! ChatTableCell
    cellForRowAtChatTable(&cell, indexPath)

    cell.alpha = 0.25
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {cell.alpha = 1

    })

    return cell
}


 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let cellCount = chatTableView.visibleCells.count
    let alphaInterval:CGFloat = 1.0 / CGFloat(cellCount / 2)

    for (index,cell) in (chatTableView.visibleCells as 
    [UITableViewCell]).enumerated() {

        if index > cellCount / 2 {
            // cell.alpha = CGFloat(index) * alphaInterval
            cell.alpha = CGFloat(cellCount - index) * (alphaInterval)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the first cell (fading it out) and adding a new one at the bottom (maybe fading it in)

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: traying to scroll frist cell and when it scroll ineed to fade out

Comment: So you want the first (or top) cell to fade out as it scrolls off the screen?

Comment: yes this what i want